# iPhone Development - Memory limitation for iphone application

Tags: iphone, memory

Can anyone point into the right direction here. I want to respond when my application receives memory warning, (i want to know how to respond to this notification). Plus, How much memory can i wire with my application?

Any articles or book reference would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your app gets a memory warning (such as in your view controller's `didReceiveMemoryWarning` method) you need to release any non-critical data. Anything that you're using that cached, for example, or that can be regenerated, should be dumped.

For example, if your app crunches some numbers and stores the result in a big array, if you're not actively using that array, you should release it. Then, regenerate it when you need it again.

A little more information is here:
[Observing Low-Memory Warnings](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ApplicationEnvironment/chapter_3_section_5.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW49)

Comment: Link moved... https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ApplicationEnvironment/chapter_3_section_5.html

Answer (score 4):

I've heard informally that warnings get issued when your application hits about 22 MB. (Any allocated memory is included -- the iPhone keeps everything in physical RAM and doesn't page out to any other storage.) Given that the phone only has 128 MB of total RAM, this seems plausible.

That limit does not include the memory used by shared system libraries, such as the Objective-C runtime. And while I'm not entirely sure on this, I don't think WebKit's memory usage is included for the UIWebView component, as I believe WebKit is always loaded (but again, not 100% sure on that).

The best thing to do when you hit this limit is free anything that you can easily regenerate or re-read from input files, such as views, images, and cached data.

Comment: Yeah that seems about right based on my experience. No clue about Safari using it's own memory though.