# What is The maximum Memory usage Limit For an Iphone Application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone Development - Memory limitation for iphone application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457568/iphone-development-memory-limitation-for-iphone-application)

Please tell me that what is the maximum Memory usage limit for an Iphone Application?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try the following article: http://www.game-developers.org/node/47#1

It contains pretty detailed information about how to check what you can do, and why you should not really count on any particular memory pool to be available (as much as it is practical, that is).